# how to create progress bar in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates in two separate variables. First date is account registration date and second is account expire date. I want to create a progress bar to show how many days left to expire.
I did the following,

PHP code:

```
$date1 = strtotime("$reg_date");
$date2 = strtotime("$expire_date");
$today = time();
$num = $today - $date1;
$den = $date2 - $date1;
$percentage = ($today - $date1) / ($date2 - $date1) * 100;
echo"
  <div id=\"progressbar\">
    <div width=$percentage%></div>
  </div>";
```

CSS code:

```css
#progressbar {
  background-color: #99cc66;
  width: 50%; 
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

It's not working and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I want something like this picture,

[image: Progress bar]

Comment: `width` is not a valid HTML attribute. You have to pass the CSS attribute through `style`. Use `echo '<div style="width: '.$percentage.'%;">';`

Answer (score 2):

This works:

PHP:

```
$date1 = strtotime("1 feb 2015"); // Register date
$date2 = strtotime("10 feb 2015"); // Expire date
$today = time();
$timePast = $today - $date1;
$duration = $date2 - $date1;
$completed  = floor(($timePast/$duration)*100);
echo "<div id='progressbar'>";
echo "<div id='completed' style='width: ".$completed."% !important;'></div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Use floor to round the answer down.

CSS:

```css
#progressbar {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#completed {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #99cc66;
}
```

The bar consists of 2 divs: one for the outline and one for the actual progress (the green bit). As the percentage increases (time passing), the width also increases. The inner div has to be `position: relative` because it is relative to the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope it works

```
<style type="text/css">
#progressbar div
{
  background-color: #99cc66;
   width: 50%; 
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;

}
</style>
<?php
$date1 = strtotime("2014-09-05 11:44:01");
$date2 = strtotime("2015-09-07 23:44:01");
$today = time();

if ($today < $date1) {
    $perentage = 0;
} else if ($today > $date2) {
    $percentage = 100;
}
else {
    $percentage = ($date2 - $today) * 100 / ($date2 - $date1);
}
?>
<div id="progressbar" style="border: 1px solid ; border-radius: 10px;">
<div style="width: <?php echo $percentage; ?>%;"><span><?php echo round($percentage,2); ?>%</span></div>
</div>
```